# Continuar numeración de tabla con un insert postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Buenas gente tengo esta duda tengo estas tablas

```
T1
| id | Nombre |
| 1  | Luis   |
| 2  | Pedro  |
| 3  | Miguel |

T2
| Nombre   |
| Fernanda |
| Angel    |
```

Como puedo realizar un insert en la tabla T1 con los datos de la tabla T2 siguiendo la numeración del id de T1, cabe decir que la tabla T1 no contiene ningún tipo de autoincrement o algo por el estilo su código de creación fue algo así

```
create table T1(
  id int,
  nombre varchar(20) 
);
```

Es decir quiero que me quede de esta manera

```
T1
| id | Nombre   |
| 1  | Luis     |
| 2  | Pedro    |
| 3  | Miguel   |
| 4  | Fernanda |
| 5  | Angel    |
```

eh tratado de hacerlo de esta manera

```
INSERT INTO T1 (  
  SELECT  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select id from T1))),
  nombre
  from(SELECT distinct nombre FROM T2 )A
);
```

Comment: Necesitas hacerlo una única vez o regularmente?

Comment: @Alfabravo regularmente

Comment: Podrías hacer un trigger after insert on T2 que inserte en T1 y usar una secuencia (sí, un sequence) para obtener los ID de un único lugar siempre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

súmale el último valor a la función `row_number`

```
INSERT INTO T1
SELECT (select MAX(id) from t1)+row_number () over (), nombre from t2
```